# Create a function that gets data from a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have had problems with this all day and can't find a solution. I need to create a function that gets data from a specific page. The id on the page needs to be passed on to the function. When I first try `alert(value)`, it works, but the next time I insert it into .ajax url, it doesen't work. What can be the problem?

```
<script> 
    function func(value){
        alert(value);
            //WORKS FINE, alertbox with content "1" appears. 

            $.ajax(
            {
                type:'GET',
                url:'<?=site_url("page/view/" + value);?>',
                //DOES NOT WORK, when i enter "page/view/1" it works. When i enter "page/view/ + value" it does not work.  
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
           );
        }

    $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to add the js variable in your php code, remove it from inside the php tags

```
url:'<?=site_url("page/view/");?>' + value,
```